# Find consecutive elements satisfying conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a simple dataframe with the columns 'Quarter' and 'Growth', and I want to find the first instance of when too consecutive entries are negative.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Quarters': ['2000q1','2000q2','2000q3','2OOOq4','2001q1','2001q2','2001q3'],
'Growth': [np.nan,10,20,-5,-6,10,-8]})
```

(The first entry is NAN because 'Growth' comes from calculating the difference between entries).

I want the code to output '2001q1', the first occurence of two consecutive negative growths. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **always exist** at least one pair chain 2 masks by `&` for bitwise AND, second is same like first only shifted values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), then get first `True` by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = df.loc[(df['Growth'].lt(0) & df['Growth'].shift().lt(0)).idxmax(), 'Quarters']
print (a)
2001q1
```

If not sure if exist 1 pair is possible use `next` with `iter` for possible specify default value if no match:

```
mask = (df['Growth'].lt(0) & df['Growth'].shift().lt(0))
a =  next(iter(df.loc[mask, 'Quarters']), 'no exist 2 negative values')
print (a)
2001q1
```

Changed data sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Quarters' : ['2000q1','2000q2','2000q3','2004q4','2001q1','2001q2','2001q3'],
'Growth' : [np.nan,10,20,5,-6,10,-8]})

print (df)
  Quarters  Growth
0   2000q1     NaN
1   2000q2    10.0
2   2000q3    20.0
3   2004q4     5.0
4   2001q1    -6.0
5   2001q2    10.0
6   2001q3    -8.0

mask = (df['Growth'].lt(0) & df['Growth'].shift().lt(0))
a =  next(iter(df.loc[mask, 'Quarters']), 'no exist 2 negative consecutive values')
print (a)
no exist 2 negative consecutive values
```

Comment: Great, the 'shift' is what I was looking for. Thanks for showing me the 'next, iter' method - I just read up on it and have added it to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Chain  DataFrame.shift¶ and DataFrame.le to boolean select within datframe

```
 a,*b,= df.loc[df.Growth.le(0)&df.Growth.shift().le(0),'Quarters'].values.tolist()
print(a)
```

Explanation

```
df.loc[df.Growth.le(0)&df.Growth.shift().le(0),'Quarters'].values.tolist()#Boolean select consecutive negative numbers in column Quaters into a list
 a,*b,=x# Unpack list x giving the first element
```

'`2001q1'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The 'shift' method is what I think is easiest for my code.

Comment: Thanks, always go for what works for you.  That way we enjoy coding.  Happy you gave me chance to answer question on this wonderful forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Quarters' :['2000q1','2000q2','2000q3','2OOOq4','2001q1','2001q2','2001q3'],
    'Growth' : [np.nan,10,20,-5,-6,10,-8]})
flag=0
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
     if rows['Growth']<0 and flag<0:
         print(rows['Quarters'])
         break
     flag=rows['Growth']
```

Explanation: using iterrows(), we can loop over a dataframe. 'flag' variable helps us to store ''Growth value for 'Quarter' just before the current value.